# ordered partitions with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, computational-mathematics

Can these two questions be solved only with a computer? (1)Using ten numbers ranging from 0 to 10 and allowed to appear more than once, how many ordered partitions are there so that the sum equals 53?  (2)Using eight numbers ranging from 4 to 7 and allowed to appear more than once, how many ordered partitions are there so that the sum equals 37?

Comment: What is the actual meaning of *ordered partition* here? Are $(1,1,1,0,0,0,10,10,10,0)$ and $(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,10,10,10)$ considered the same?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that my interpretation of *ordered partition* is the correct one, you are simply looking for (1) the coefficient of $x^{53}$ in $(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{10})^{10}$ and (2) the coefficient of $x^{37}$ in $(x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7)^8$. About (1):
$$\begin{eqnarray*} [x^{53}](1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{10})^{10}&=&[x^{53}]\frac{(1-x^{11})^{10}}{(1-x)^{10}}\\&=&[x^{53}]\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}{k}(-1)^k x^{11k}\sum_{j\geq 0}\binom{9+j}{9}x^j\\&=&\sum_{k=0}^{4}(-1)^k\binom{10}{k}\binom{62-11k}{9}\\&=&\color{red}{976626970}\end{eqnarray*}$$
and about (2):
$$\begin{eqnarray*}[x^{37}](x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7)^8 &=& [x^5](1+x+x^2+x^3)^8\\&=&[x^5]\frac{(1-x^4)^8}{(1-x)^8}\\&=&[x^5]\sum_{k=0}^{8}\binom{8}{k}(-1)^k x^{4k}\sum_{j\geq 0}\binom{7+j}{7}x^j\\&=&\sum_{k=0}^{1}(-1)^k\binom{8}{k}\binom{12-4k}{7}\\&=&\color{red}{728}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

If *ordered partition* just means *partition*, the answers to (1) and (2) are given by

$$ [y^{10}x^{53}]\prod_{k=1}^{10}\frac{1}{1-y x^{k}}=\color{red}{2897},\qquad [y^8 x^{13}]\prod_{k=1}^{4}\frac{1}{1-y x^k}=\color{red}{5}. $$

Comment: I can see the reason for your assumption, but it not what I assumed you would see take to be what I mean.  Take one partition of 53 to give 0,0,1,3,5,8,8,9,9,10 and you get 10!/2!*2!*2! possible arrangements of this

Comment: @J.M.Bergot: please clarify the actual meaning of *ordered partition* and I will modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: OOOOPPPPSSS!  Forgot to tosss out thanXXXX for your answer.

Comment: Treat a partition as a multiset and find all its possible arrangements.    In my example to find 53 you MUST use ten numbers each ranging from 0 to 10 ; a partition is 0,1,2,5,5,6,6,8,8,10,10 has the required ten numbers and has 10!/2!*2!*2! arrangements  You can see that the possibilities quickly explode and either you use acres of paper or you must put the problem into a computer.  I can see of no way of finding the number of ordered partitions as described other than my listing them.  I asked the question to see if an other question could be answered.  This I could send if requested. ThanX!

Comment: But different arrangements count as different partitions or not? That is the key point. If the answer is "yes", my answer above is enough, otherwise, we have to change the involved generating functions and switch to EGFs.

Comment: NO.  As above, take each partitions and treat as a multiset to find all its possible arrangements using all ten digits including 0's.  Your example considered them to be the same; I consider them to be different.  Perhaps it would be better if I sent in the puzzle that prompted this question?

Comment: All right, then your problem can be tackled by considering a bivariate version of the usual partition function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function

Comment: For instance, (1) boils down to computing $$ [y^{10}x^{53}]\prod_{k=1}^{10}\frac{1}{1-y x^k} $$

Comment: And $(2)$ boils down to computing $$[y^8 x^{13}]\prod_{k=1}^4\frac{1}{1-y x^k}$$

Comment: To insure that you understand, I'll avoid the word 'partition'.  Consider five space in a row and use the numbers from 0-5 to give a sum of 5.  Seven ways @number of arrangements of each of these multisets: 1,1,1,1,1 @1;0,0,0,1,4 @20; 0,0,0,2,3,@20; 0,0,1,2,2 @30; 0,0,1,1,3 @20;0,1,1,1,2 @20; and 0,0,0,0,5 @5 to give a total of 126 arrangements.

Comment: It would be easier to avoid the word *ordered*, instead, and just call *partition* a partition. Anyway, my two comments above give the answer.

Comment: ThanXXX again!  I'll enter the question on "arrangement of numbered balls in distinct cyclinders". . . .coming in a few minutes.

Comment: @J.M.Bergot: there is no need to deface your original question now that you got not only an answer, but also an answer to an alternative interpretation of your wording choice.

Comment: Just in=  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1920681/arrangements-of-numbered-balls-in-distinct-cyclinders